# Vite module load order - calling a named import before default import evaluated

Tags: module, loading, vite, preload, immer

I am using `immer` for state immutability in a Vite React application. If you want to load the immer plugin for drafting Maps and Sets (as well as object and array literals) you need to call `enableMapSet()` before importing the immer default export. More detail at https://immerjs.github.io/immer/installation/

Unfortunately in my Vite build process, the importing and running of `enableMapSet()` (which is defined in the first two lines of main.tsx) happens too late. The default import of immer has already completed. This leads to errors like...

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: [Immer] The plugin for 'MapSet' has not been loaded into Immer. To enable the plugin, import and call `enableMapSet()` when initializing your application.
```

However, I don't know if I can control the load order. In my app `immer` is defined as a peer dependency. It is a second-order dependency because my app depends on https://www.npmjs.com/package/@lauf/store-edit/v/2.0.0-alpha.0 which in turn has a declared external dependency on immer.
I have tried to ensure that no import of any library takes place before my import and invocation of `enableMapSet()` in main.tsx. However, somehow or another the import of @lauf/store-edit happens first as demonstrated by putting breakpoints at those lines in Chrome and seeing which comes first. It's possible there is preload behaviour which is causing everything to load before I get to call `enableMapSet()` but I don't know how to influence this. I attempted to prevent preload like this in `vite.config.ts` but it had no effect...

```js
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  build: {
    modulePreload: {
      resolveDependencies: () => [],
    },
  },
});
```

Is there any way to influence the load order in Vite, to ensure that the import and invocation of `enableMapSet()` happens before loading other dependencies loaded by `main.tsx`?

Answer (score 0):

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { enableMapSet } from 'immer';
import { reducers } from './reducers';

enableMapSet();

export function configureStore() {
    const rootReducer = combineReducers({
        ...reducers,
    });

    return configureStore({
        reducer: rootReducer,
    });
}

const store = configureStore();
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
export default store;
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution Alyssa, but the context of using the Vite loader and the fact that its not me loading immer is what creates the complexity, (if I was in charge of load order and could call enableMapSet first then I wouldn't have the problem. The example you shared doesn't involve Vite and I don't see what in your example influences the load order (to make sure it gets called before some other dependency has already loaded Immer).

Comment: This error is not because the call order is incorrect, you only need to import enableMapSet where it is used (such as redux) and call enableMapSet().

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).